# Save a *.xlsm file as *.xlsx and suppress the pop-up

Tags: vba, excel

The current active workbook is a macro-enabled one.

After performing some automated data manipulation, I want to save it as a new macro-free workbook (thus .xlsx instead of .xlsm). To do this, I recorded and edited a macro:

```
Dim newFilePath As string
newFileFullName = "C:\List.xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFileFullName, FileFormat _
:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

Workbooks.Open Filename:=newFileFullName
Windows("List.xlsx").Activate
```

However, whenever I run this macro, a [window](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/u7b9alfpwjui3sv/Screenshot%202014-04-19%2022.21.35.png) keeps popping up, asking for confirmation that I want to change the file format.

How can I suppress this pop-up and default it to "Yes"?

Comment: try to add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Thanks @simoco

Comment: The problem is that the answer was posted as a comment, so there's no answer to accept. If @simoco comes back and post this as an answer, then this answer should be deleted, otherwise this need to stay here and be self-accepted after two days.