# Saving a .xlsm as .xlsx using Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a C# program that runs a macro existing inside an xlsm file and after this macro has finished its operations, I would like to save this xlsm as .xlsx file. This is the code that runs and saves the macro file as xlsx:

```
void RunMacro(string macroFilename, string xlsxFilePath)
{
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook;
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(macroFilename);
    app.Visible = true;
    app.Run("Main");
    workbook.SaveAs(xlsxFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
    app.Workbooks.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

Now, the issue is that in the line workbook.SaveAs(), I will get a prompt like this from Excel:
[image: Following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks]

So how can I make it programatically that "Yes" is the default option here and this prompt is automatically closed without needing to click on anything?

EDIT:
The following threads (linked as the reason for closing this question) are not a solution:

[How do I save an XLSM file as an XLSX file without prompting the user about lost data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740116/how-do-i-save-an-xlsm-file-as-an-xlsx-file-without-prompting-the-user-about-lost)

[Save a *.xlsm file as *.xlsx and suppress the pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175138/save-a-xlsm-file-as-xlsx-and-suppress-the-pop-up)

Basically, there are two proposed solutions in these threads:

1. Set `application.DisplayAlerts = false` and call `workbook.SaveAs(xlsxFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);`
   This still results in a prompt coming up where it is necessary to select 'Yes'. Here is my code:

```
void RunMacro(string macroFilename, string xlsxFilePath)
{
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook;
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(macroFilename);
    app.Visible = true;
    app.DisplayAlerts = false;
    app.Run("Main");
    workbook.SaveAs(xlsxFilePath,Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
    app.Workbooks.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

2. Use `Workbook.SaveCopyAs(xlsxFilePath)`

This method call does circumvent the Excel prompt, but the xlsx file that it produces is corrupted:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
void RunMacro(string macroFilename, string xlsxFilePath)
{
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook;
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(macroFilename);
    app.Visible = true;
    app.Run("Main");
    workbook.SaveCopyAs(xlsxFilePath);
    app.Workbooks.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Hey did you find a solution to default yes as answer to pop up?